# Is there any tool through which i can join data from two tables - One in hive & Other in cassandra. Also I have to run this job through oozie

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, datastax, oozie

I have one table in hive & one table in cassandra.
I want to join them, then based on result, store some data into cassandra.

```
Ques 1) Is it possible?
Ques 2) Suggest the solution that can be run through oozie.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

You have to export the data from Hive(delimited data) and export them into cassandra and then apply join and vice versa.

These are possible in Oozie.

Comment: Thanks Kushagra.. Can you pls tell how to export the data from hive to cassandra & it will be part of job, not a one time process.

Comment: To export from Hive - 
"INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '<dir>' SELECT * FROM <Table Name>
To import in cassandra-
Refer http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/simple-data-importing-and-exporting-with-cassandra

If you feel you are satisfied please mark it as accepted so that others can also get some help.